# New CPU, MoBo, and RAM; same SSD and OS. Running EXTREMELY slow and laggy now

Tags: windows-10, ssd, cpu, performance

I just upgraded my PC:

i5-9600K
Asus ROG Strix z390-E Gaming
2x8GB DDR4 SDRAM

The PC is now running extremely slow and lagging like crazy. A click and drag on the desktop takes about 10 seconds to process. My games are running at 1 fps. I have no idea what could be causing this. I changed the BIOS `CPU Fan Monitor` to ignore because the PC throws a "CPU Fan Error" error and doesn't boot. The only other thing I can think of is that I installed the RAM in the 2nd set of DIMM slots but the RAM was recognized so I don't think that is causing it. The Motherboard is refurbished.

My only other option is to re-install Windows and I don't think that will fix it. The PC appears to be lagging even in the BIOS menu.

How can this problem be resolved?

Comment: Yes; The motherboard could be the problem.  Specifically it could be the socket.  This is supported by the fact the POST is throwing a CPU fan error.  Make sure all modules are installed in a supported configuration

Comment: This may sound trivial, but is the fan spinning?

Comment: Yes, all fans are spinning. I am using a H80i GT water cooler. I am kind of confused because the cooler manual says to plug it into the CPU Fan header, but there are all sorts of other headers on this mobo such as "Pump Fan" and stuff so I dont know where to put it. I currently have it plugged into the "CPU Fan" header.

Comment: @Ramhound could you please elaborate what do you mean by the modules?

Comment: Your system having water cooler is important.  You did not indicate that in your question.  **The water cool fan should be specified by the manual for your motherboard.**  By "module",  I mean your memory module, make sure you have them installed in a supported configuration.

Comment: _Do not plug the pump into CPU fan header_. It should always run at full speed. The CPU header will be adjusted to CPU temperature, this is not how pump should work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by doing a clean install of Windows. I just need to import all of my files and programs to my new partition now.

Answer (score 0):

I am no hardware expert and I also agree that re-installing windows would not work as it lags even in BIOS menu...

How about resetting your motherboard to factory mode(there must be a way to do this in the motherboard manual) and test fresh windows with default bios settings?

Comment: Yes this is what I am going to try next. However, the computer refuses to boot unless I change a setting in the BIOS (setting "CPU Fan" monitor to "Ignore")

Answer (score 0):

Check Bios for STATUS/Diagnostics Page - looking for high **TEMP**. Make sure new CPU and cooler makes good contact with thermal paste between them !! If temp is high.

Big hardware changes will require new drivers in windows and windows probably won't like new hardware changes for security reasons!!

Check your windows device manager for any hardware driver problems, if any get that sorted from official websites. **Important !! Check logs & performance monitor for clues!**

If you do run bios defaults check some basics like mentioned bellow.

Booting options in bios (UEFI vs legacy) modes should be same as your win install.
Windows 8-10 specific options in bios should be checked as applicable.
SSD works better in AHCI mode in bios settings if not checked.
If using new M.2 port for SSD, its got its own options. check hardware specs and adjust if applicable.

Enable any disables hardware like wifi/LAN options.
Performance options like fast boot and win8/10 options matters and can potentially hinder you from getting into bios and boot options

You have multi channel memory bus, offset dimms according to M/B manual, usually not right next to each other in my experience. This will help with performance.
Make sure you are using compatable hardware for your M/B.

Not all fans have fan speed controllers and not all fan headers on M/B's are the same. Make sure to check that fan is plugged to supported header labeled "CPU_fan" or similar.(number of pins count here and connector notch orientation).

Hopefully its helpful in some way